# Multi-provision, multi-vm Vagrantfile vm filtering

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When provisioning for EC2, I only want the 'app' vm.  When provisioning locally, I want 'app' and 'pg'.  I'm having trouble writing a single Vagrantfile that can cater to both scenarios.

I'd like to invoke this by just using a provider as a way to make it work:

```
vagrant up --provider=aws
```

vs

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

AWS would spawn just app.  Virtualbox would spawn app and pg.

I'm using vagrant 1.7.2

I have something like the following Vagrantfile:

```
...
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
    ...
    config.vm.define "app" do |app|
        # setup app here
        ...
        config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vbox, override|
            # setup virtualbox for app vm here
            ...
        end
        ...
        config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
            # setup aws for app vm here
            ...
        end
    end
    ...
    config.vm.define "pg" do |pg|
        # setup postgres here
        ...
    end
...
end
```

Edit: clarified invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, you will do `vagrant up app --provider=aws` for AWS where only app will be started (and provisioned if needed) or `vagrant up` if you want local and both VM will be created

However Vagrant does support running Vagrantfile with multiple number of providers at the same time, one thing you can do is to create VM/environment for each provider and then rename the `.vagrant` directory after it has been created.

Comment: So I was aware we could bring them up individually.  What I really wanted was a simple invocation (vagrant up --provider=<chosen>) without any changes so it could be dead simple and key'd off the provider.  Currently, with that invocation, I spawn multiple vms where I only want one.